# How to serve static files with nginx after using npm run build with webpack

Tags: node.js, nginx

after generating a development build with npm run build i get the message saying 
"Tip: built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server.
  Opening index.html over file:// won't work."

What is the best way to do this with nginx? Currently to test it i am using an npm module called serve.

Also, if i got to my homepage at mydomain.com and search for a user, everything works like it is supposed to, redirecting me to mydomain.com/users/brad but if i then do a url search formydomain.com/users/brad i get a not found error, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, when I have to serve static content with nginx, it often looks like :

```
   location /static {
       alias $myroot/staticfiles;
   }
```

Also, if you haven't already, read the NginX guide to [Serving Static Content](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/serving-static-content/).

Answer (score 0):

If your are familiar with the Docker technology i would recommend to use a Docker Nginx Container and add your static content from the Webpack Buildflow to your container (this can be automated with a build server). Have a look at the following Docker Image from Nginx: https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/.

Otherwise you have to install nginx on your Server where you host your Homepage. For this have a look at your Server OS and reach out to the web for a detailed nginx setup for your server. Without any configurations nginx will serve the static content on Linux-like server from `/usr/share/nginx/html`

If you only have FTP Access to your server you can transfer your built files via FTP/SFTP to a specific folder e.g /myHomepage and then your static content is server from yourdomain.de/myHompage.